# dynamic <div> content on change <select>

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

what i want to do:
1.)  is shown on page after first load.
When an user selects one or multiple options dynamic content is loaded into a `<div>`

2.) in this first dynamic `<div>` an other php page echos a second  with further entries.

--- till here my code works just fine ---

3.) after selecting one or multiple options in this second `<select>` in the first dynamic `<div>` a second dynamic `<div>` should be printed with another `<select>`

But after selecting entries from second  nothing is shown in second dynamic

Example:
- Page Load: First  Cars, Bikes, Trucks, Planes...
- I choose "Cars"
- First dynamic `<div>` shows: `<select>` Mustang, Chrysler, Jeep, etc...
- I choose Chrysler
(till here my code works fine)
- Second dynamic `<div>` shows:  red, white, brown, yellow, ...

My Code:
Page which is loaded in browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Unbenanntes Dokument</title>
</head>
<body>

<?
include_once('includes/functions.inc.php');
$conn = connection();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Faecher WHERE Fach_Studienabschnitt = 1 ORDER BY Fachname ASC";
$sql_erg_VKH_Faecher = send_sql($sql);

mysql_close($conn); 
?>

<!-- the select -->
<select name="Fach[]" size="25" multiple="multiple" id="Fach">
    <?

        echo '<optgroup label="Vorklinik-Humanmedizin">';
        while($vkhfaecher = mysql_fetch_array($sql_erg_VKH_Faecher)){

            echo "<option value=".$vkhfaecher['Fach_ID'].">".$vkhfaecher['Fachname']."(".$faecher[$vkhfaecher['Fach_ID']]['Fragenanzahl'].")"."</option>";
        }
        echo '</optgroup>';

    ?>
</select>

<!-- the DIVs -->
<div id="Semester"></div>
<div id="Tags"></div>

<!-- the jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#Fach').change(function(event) {
   var form_data = $('#Fach').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax_reload.php",
        type: "post",
        data: form_data,
        success: function(data){
            //adds the echoed response to our container
            $("#Semester").html(data);
        }
    });          
}); 

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$('#Semester').change(function(event) {
   var form_data = $('#Semester').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax_reload.php",
        type: "post",
        data: form_data,
        success: function(data){
            //adds the echoed response to our container
            $("#Tags").html(data);
        }
    });          
}); 

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

ajax_reload.php which dynamically loads content from mysql_db:

```
<?
session_start();
include_once('includes/functions.inc.php');

$conn = connection();

if(isset($_POST['Fach'])){
foreach($_POST['Fach'] as $elem){
    $sql_fach_temp1 .= "T1.Fach_ID = ".$elem." OR ";        
    $sql_fach_temp2 .= "T2.Fach_ID = ".$elem." OR ";                
}
$sql_fach_temp1 = substr($sql_fach_temp1, 0, -4);
$sql_fach_temp2 = substr($sql_fach_temp2, 0, -4);   
$_SESSION['ajax_sql'] = "(".$sql_fach_temp1.") AND (".$sql_fach_temp2.")";

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT T3.Semester,T3.Semester_ID FROM Fragen T1, Faecher T2, Semester T3 WHERE (".$sql_fach_temp1.") AND (".$sql_fach_temp2.") AND T1.Semester_ID = T3.Semester_ID";
$FaecherSemester_temp = send_sql($sql);

    echo '<select name="Semester[]" size="25" multiple="multiple" id="Semester">';
    while($semesterliste = mysql_fetch_array($FaecherSemester_temp)){
        echo "<option value=".$semesterliste['Semester_ID'].">".$semesterliste['Semester']."</option>";
    }   
    echo "</select>";

}

if(isset($_POST['Semester'])){
echo $_SESSION['ajax_sql']."ja";
foreach($_POST['Semester'] as $elem){
    $sql_semester_temp .= "T3.Semester_ID = ".$elem." OR ";             
}
$sql_semester_temp = substr($sql_semester_temp, 0, -4);

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT T4.Tag, T4.Tag_ID FROM Fragen T1, Faecher T2, Semester T3, Tags T4, Frage_Tags T5 WHERE ".$_SESSION['ajax_sql']." AND (".$sql_semester_temp.") AND T1.Semester_ID = T3.Semester_ID AND T4.Tag_ID = T5.Tag_ID AND T1.Frage_ID = T5.Frage_ID";

$FaecherSemesterTags_temp = send_sql($sql);


    echo '<select name="Tags[]" size="25" multiple="multiple" id="Tags">';
    while($tagsliste = mysql_fetch_array($FaecherSemesterTags_temp)){
        echo "<option value=".$tagsliste['Tags_ID'].">".$tagsliste['Tags']."</option>";
    }   
    echo "</select>";
}



mysql_close($conn);  
?>
```

I tried to copy the ajax code into ajax_reload.php so that the cod is echoed into the dynamic `<div>`, but no response...

any idea?

thanks a lot!

Comment: Two issues: 1) You have duplicate IDs: Both a DIV and SELECT with `id="Semester"`, and a DIV and SELECT with `id="Tags"`. 2) Since you're loading the SELECTs dynamically, you need to use event delegation to bind your handlers.

Comment: hmm changed the IDs uniqe names. i'm quite new to ajax. any tip for "event delegation"? one ajax-code for all .change events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `#Semester` SELECT is added dynamically, you need to use event delegation:

```
$('#SemesterDiv').on("change", "#Semester", function(event) {
   var form_data = $('#Semester').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax_reload.php",
        type: "post",
        data: form_data,
        success: function(data){
            //adds the echoed response to our container
            $("#TagsDiv").html(data);
        }
    });          
});
```

I'm assuming you renamed `<div id="Semester">` to `<div id="SemesterDiv">`, and similarly for the `Tags` DIV.

Comment: I performed all changes to my code. renamed the <div> etc.. but the second dynamic <div id="TagsDiv"> stays empty after selecting one or multiple options from #Semester 

script code should be on main page, right? not loaded dynamically with div, right?

Comment: I had an extra parenthesis in my code, I just fixed it. Does that solve it?